# How to decompose the spinor kinetic term of $D=10$ SYM in terms of lower dimensional parts?

Tags: supersymmetry, representation-theory, spinors, yang-mills, dirac-matrices

The kinetic term for the spinors in $D=10$ SYM is $\lambda \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is a 16 component Majorana-Weyl spinor and $\gamma^\mu$ is a 16 by 16 matrix satisfying $\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\}=2\eta^{\mu \nu}$,  with $\mu=0 \; \text{to} \; 9$. The matrix $\gamma^\mu$ is the 10 dimensional analogue of the Pauli matrices $\sigma^m$, $m=0 \; \text{to} \; 4$

I want to decompose $\lambda \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \lambda$ in terms of $SO(1,3)$ and a $SO(6)$, where the $SO(6)$ part is divided in a $\textbf{3}$ and a $\bar{\textbf{3}}$ of $SU(3)$. The form of the terms I should get, ignoring possible constant coefficients, are

$\lambda^\alpha \sigma^m_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} \partial_m \bar{\lambda}^{\dot{\alpha}}, \quad  \lambda^{\alpha}_j \sigma^m_{\alpha \dot{\alpha}} \partial_m \bar{\lambda}^{\dot{\alpha},j}, \quad \lambda^{\alpha}_j \bar{\partial}^j \lambda_\alpha, \quad \bar{\lambda}^{\dot{\alpha},j}\partial_j \bar{\lambda}_\dot{\alpha}, \quad \epsilon_{ijk}\bar{\lambda}^{\dot{\alpha},i} \bar{\partial}^j \bar{\lambda}^k_\dot{\alpha}, \quad \epsilon^{ijk}\lambda^\alpha_i \partial_j \lambda_{\alpha,k} $

where lower (upper) indices $i,j,k=1,2,3$ correspond to the $\textbf{3}$ ($\bar{\textbf{3}}$) of $SU(3)$.

The question is: how can I get the terms I wrote in a systematic way, that is, starting from $\lambda \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \lambda$ and arriving at them with the right coefficients? I think this can be done decomposing the $D=10$ gamma matrices, but I am not sure how to do that.